# Calculating the energy produced in watts in Alcator C-Mod

Tags: energy, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I calculated the energy in joules that a deuterium-tritium fusion reaction releases and found `2.81829046e-12`J.
I then read on some MIT articles that the [Alcator C-Mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcator_C-Mod) reactor reached 300 trillions fusion reactions per second.
Logically, I multiplied `2.81829046e-12` by `300e12`, to find the energy released during one second of runtime. I found approximately `845.48`J. 
And, I know that `1W = 1J/s`.
So in theory, the reactor should have produced `845.48`W of power.
But this seems so very very low, considering 4MW were used to heat the plasma.
So that's why I came here, where have I made a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake here. Alcator C-Mod was never meant to be a prototype power plant; rather, it was a research reactor that explored the feasibility of having a high-field, small reactor rather than the huge donuts everyone else was building. So 1 kW is actually pretty reasonable.